# code needs some explaination

Tags: php

I have this code and was wondering what is it doing or if there is a better way to do it.

```
if (eregi("1$|3$|5$|7$|9$", $o))
{
     $tablecolor='bgcolor="#cccccc"';
     $bgcolor='bgcolor="#bcbcbc"';
} 
else
{
     $tablecolor='bgcolor="#bcbcbc"';   
     $bgcolor='bgcolor="#cccccc"';
}
```

I am kinda confused about `"1$|3$|5$|7$|9$", $o` part

Comment: ereg is depreciated and should not be used

Comment: Seem like a function to make alternating table row colors. I'd use CSS tr:odd

Comment: I don't understand the down-votes, His question seems valid enough.

Answer (score 3):

First of all `eregi()` is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

That searches in `$o` if it ends in `1` or `3` or `5` or `7` or `9`, assuming $o is an ID, can be integer or some string like `div1` or `div3`, if it matches it sets different colors for your html.

Comment: the dollar checks the end of the string.

Comment: yes ... forgot to mention, I already mention `div1`, `div3` :)

Answer (score 2):

That is a regular expression pattern, and here are the important bits:

1. The `|` means "or", so you can break it down to `1$` OR `3$` OR ...
2. The `$` means "if the end of the line is here". So that means "if the end of the line is 1 or..."

This means the expression is looking for any line which ends in an odd integer.

It is essentially an algorithm to apply different styling to odd and even rows. There are drastically cleaner ways to do it if you can author the HTML yourself (i.e. css classes for odd and even), but sometimes you have to work with what you are given :-)

Answer (score 2):

[eregi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) is a deprecated php function that runs a case insensitive regular expression search on a string (in this case $o).

The dollar sign checks the end of a string, so what your function does is check if the string ends in 1, 3, 5, 7 or 9 and sets the tablecolor accordingly.